# LXML unable to retrieve webpage with error "failed to load HTTP resource"

Tags: python, lxml, lxml.html

Hi so I tried opening the link below in a browser and it works but not in the code. The link is actually a combination of a news site and then the extension of the article called from another file url.txt. I tried the code with a normal website (www.google.com) and it works perfectly.

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import *
import urllib2
import nltk, re, pprint
import mechanize #html form filling
import lxml.html

with open("url.txt","r") as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
#print first_line
url = "http://channelnewsasia.com/&s" + (first_line)
t = lxml.html.parse(url)
print t.find(".//title").text
```

And this is the error I am getting.

[image]

And this is the content of url.txt

/news/asiapacific/australia-to-send-armed/1284790.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `&s` part of the url - it is definitely not needed:

```
url = "http://channelnewsasia.com" + first_line
```

Also, url parts are better be joined using [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
from urlparse import urljoin
import lxml.html

BASE_URL = "http://channelnewsasia.com" 

with open("url.txt") as f:
    first_line = f.readline()

url = urljoin(BASE_URL, first_line)
t = lxml.html.parse(url)
print t.find(".//title").text
```

prints:

```
Australia to send armed personnel to MH17 site - Channel NewsAsia
```

Comment: Hi thanks man! However I'm still getting this error with your codes. http://tinypic.com/r/al2l5e/8 Is there smth wrong on my side?

Comment: @Jmo just a simple check, does replacing `first_line = f.readline()` with `first_line = f.readline().strip()` help? If not, could you print out `url` variable value before calling `parse()` so that I can see what the actual url is being retrieved and parsed? Thanks.

Comment: Yup it works now thanks! Is there anyway I can get the full content of the article also?

Comment: @Jmo sure, `print '\n'.join(t.xpath('.//div[@class="news_detail"]/div/p/text()'))`.

Comment: Btw man is there a way of text analysis whereby I'm able to isolate the time/location from the article?