# LXML unable to retrieve webpage using link from file

Tags: python, lxml

Hi this may look like a repost but is not. I have recently posted a similar question but this is another issue that links to that problem. So as seen from the previous question([LXML unable to retrieve webpage with error "failed to load HTTP resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007501/lxml-unable-to-retrieve-webpage-with-error-failed-to-load-http-resource)), I am now able to read and print the article if the link is the first line of the file. However, once I try to do it multiple times, it comes back with the error (http://tinypic.com/r/2rr2mau/8)

```
import lxml.html

def fetch_article_content_cna (i):
    BASE_URL = "http://channelnewsasia.com" 
    f = open('cnaurl2.txt')
    line = f.readlines()
    print line [i]
    url = urljoin(BASE_URL, line[i])
    t = lxml.html.parse(url)
    #print t.find(".//title").text
    content = '\n'.join(t.xpath('.//div[@class="news_detail"]/div/p/text()'))
    return content
```

cnaurl2.txt

```
/news/world/tripoli-fire-rages-as/1287826.html
/news/asiapacific/korea-ferry-survivors/1287508.html
```

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest complete program that demonstrates your error. Copy-paste that small program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: Also, please don't post link to image sites. Copy-paste the text of the error messages into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
url = urljoin(BASE_URL, line[i].strip())
```